# Synthesis of sodium methoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry

For synthesis of sodium methoxide, can we use sodium hydroxide in methanol and slow evaporation after dissolving sodium hydroxide?

Answer (score 3):

No, all that does is give you back your NaOH. Its not a strong enough base to completely deprotonate methanol.
I use sodium metal in methanol, cooled in ice/water bath and stirred under nitrogen for safety.